# React Form not sending POST data to API

Tags: python, reactjs, django

React code for Frontend

```
function InputsSignUp(){
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('/api/user/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };
  
    return (
        <>
              <Container fluid="sm" style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <h1>{email}</h1>
      <h1>{password}</h1>
    <Form>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicUsername">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group>


      <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </Button>
      </Form>
      </Container>
        </>
    )
}
```

Python code for Backend

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hello")
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        user = User.objects.create(
            #username=data['username'],
            email=data['email'],
            password="hello",
        )
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'User created successfully'})
```

I am trying to send data from frontend react to backend to create a user and store the data.
But whenever I submit the data it does not reach the given api point.

While using POSTMAN to send the data I am successfully able to create the user. Is there anything wrong with the react code?

Comment: use the full API URL in fetch ` fetch('http://localhost:xxxx/api/user/',...`

Comment: and also add react server url in 'ALLOWED_HOSTS'

Comment: @Atom I have created the react app inside the django project so the host is still localhost:8000 for it, i tried adding the entire URL in fetch but it still does not work, any other suggestions?